# Creating a dataset by matching one dataset to another

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, map

I have a dataset as a list paired terms `{fruit1,fruit2}`:

Example: `dataset1 = {{apple,orange}, {banana, grape},{blueberry,orange}, {kiwi,cherry}, {banana,kiwi}};`

and a reference dataset as a list of with element is in the structure of `{fruit,color}`

Example: `dataset2 ={{apple,green},{banana,yellow},{blueberry,blue},{cherry,red},{orange,orange},{kiwi,brown}};`

I need to match the colors to the fruit in dataset1 with those provided in dataset2 and append them to dataset1

Result should be,

```
dataset1 = {{apple,orange,green,orange}, {banana,grape,yellow,purple},{blueberry,orange,blue,orange}, {kiwi,cherry,brown,red}, {banana,kiwi,yellow,brown}};
```

Is there any help for this to map a function for this?

Answer (score 7):

Here, a good choice of data structure simplifies things greatly. Make an `Association[]` from the fruit-color list:

```
fruitColor = AssociationThread @@ 
     Transpose[{{"apple", "green"}, {"banana", "yellow"}, {"blueberry", "blue"},
                {"cherry", "red"}, {"orange", "orange"}, {"kiwi", "brown"},
                {"grape", "purple"}}]
```

(Note that you missed `"grape"` in the original list, and it's nicer to work with strings so that you don't have too many dangling symbols.)

From there, `Lookup[]` works nicely:

```
fruitList = {{"apple", "orange"}, {"banana", "grape"}, {"blueberry", "orange"},
             {"kiwi", "cherry"}, {"banana", "kiwi"}};

Function[fruits, Join[fruits, Lookup[fruitColor, fruits]]] /@ fruitList
   {{"apple", "orange", "green", "orange"}, {"banana", "grape", "yellow", "purple"},
    {"blueberry", "orange", "blue", "orange"}, {"kiwi", "cherry", "brown", "red"},
    {"banana", "kiwi", "yellow", "brown"}}
```

Comment: Thank you ! this is perfect and simplifies the process!

Comment: @NicC. Since "this is perfect" please consider [Accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer.